# С++/CLI Одномерный массив array

Tags: c++-cli

Есть массив `array < Code^ >^ buf` (уже инициализирован) в управляемом классе `Archiver`, где `Code` - структура, имеющая поле `value(long)` и еще 1 структура `Item`, также имеющая `value(int)`. Мне надо присвоить элементу `i` ссылку на объект `Code code`.

Как правильно обращаться к массиву?

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
void Archiver::Item::collapse(Archiver::Code code)
{
        if (left && right)
        {
             left->collapse(code + 0);
             right->collapse(code + 1);
        }
        else
             buf[(byte)value] = code;
}

// Объявления на всякий случай:

ref class Archiver
{
    ref struct Code
    {
        long value;
        char size;
        Code() :value(0), size(0) {}
        Code(Code% c) :value(c.value), size(c.size) {}

        Code operator+(char b);
        //Code% Get(int i) { return ^(this); }
    };

    ref struct Item
    {
        long count;
        int value;
        Item^ left = nullptr, ^right = nullptr;
        Item();
        Item(int value) { this->value = value; }
        Item(int value, long count) 
        {                                                       
             this->value = value; 
             this->count = count; 
        } 
        ~Item();
        void collapse(Archiver::Code path);
    };

    array<Code^ >^ buf;
    ...
}
```

P.S Пишу архиватор с шифрованием Хаффмана

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky уточните, пожалуйста, где тут [tag:c++].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала, `buf` находится в `Archiver`, а вы пытаетесь достучаться до него из `Archiver::Item` — там его нету просто.

Во-вторых, у вас `Code` — это `ref struct`, значит, и передавать его надо по ссылке. То есть не `collapse(Archiver::Code code)`, а `collapse(Archiver::Code^ code)`.

Comment: спасибо, понял!

Comment: @Xambey: Пожалуйста!